# Accepting any array as a parameter

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I am trying to get getIntArrayString to accept parameters given to it, unlike abc.getAverage which uses the field testArray.

edit: Forgot to ask the question.
how would I be able to send parameters such as test1 to getIntArrayString()?

```
private int testArray;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] testArray = new int[]{2,4,6,8,9};
    ArrayHW abc = new ArrayHW(testArray);
    System.out.printf(abc.getAverage());
    int[] test1= new int[]{3,4,5,6,7};
    System.out.printf("Array Values: %s\n",ahw.getIntArrayString());
    int[] test1= new int[]{3,4,5,6,7} 
    System.out.printf("Array Values: %s\n",ahw.getIntArrayString());
 }
```

Comment: Now that you've clarified a bit what you wanted, [here's the Java tutorial on methods.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a method named getIntArrayString inside another class. If you want to send the values of test1, the method getIntArrayString must have a parameter of test1's datatype. For example,

```
public int getIntArrayString(int [] x)
 {

 }
```

You should review your knowledge of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Having two variables called testArray may seem a little confusing, but it's not syntactiacally wrong. However, it's less confusing to read your code if you don't, and even better if you remove any unused variables.

You are not posting any error messages, but I suppose you can't compile because you haven't declared any variable "ahw", and ahw.getIntArrayString() produces a compiler error.

In general, in order to be able to send a parameter of type int[] to a method it would be declared like this:

```
public String getIntArrayString(int[] intArray) { ... }
```

And you would call it like this

```
System.out.println(x.getIntArrayList(test1));
```

where test1 is an int array as declared in your own code.